# :hover an element with :active css loses the css

Tags: css

I have the following CSS:

```
.point.active,
.point:active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #31b0d5;
    border-color: #269abc;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7zmjvaxL/

This is working. But when the element is active and I hover over it, it loses the CSS colors. How I can keep the color if the element is active and if I hover over it?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of element is this pointing at? `:active` is generally used for UI interactives, so more details would be useful.

Comment: it is a radio button (I am using Bootstrap)

Comment: Can you add your HTML, I'm having lots of trouble replicating this.

Comment: Or better yet, make a jsfiddle that demonstrates it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap comes with a number of default settings for certain elements.

In your case it is forcing this rule:

```
.btn-default.active:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #d4d4d4;
    border-color: #8c8c8c;
}
```

Which is overriding your own rule set.

The best bet is to *remove* the class `btn-default`, because its not really a default button, its a customised one, and then add CSS rules for your element.

[For example, this jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7zmjvaxL/1/):

```
.btn-point {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the information. what I am really trying to do is toggle a div when I click in this button. So, unactivating it show come to the btn-default state. Gonna create a fiddle with it... But I think it is better create a new question, but maybe if you stay around, I will post it here too. Thanks.
Here: http://jsfiddle.net/2mpca6uc/

Comment: Just for referene this was my end approach: https://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/xo2zm8oa/ Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.point.active,
.point:active,
.point:active:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #31b0d5;
    border-color: #269abc;
}
```

Do you have `.point:hover{}` somewhere ?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I don't have the `.point:hover{}`. Tried the code, but isn't working